# importing data from excel by two coloums

Tags: import

i want to import two coloumns from excel what basically works:

```
data = Import["/Users/name/file.xlsx", {"Data", 1, All, {1, 2}}]
```

The main "problem" i got is the data are sorted by a pair like

```
{{0.579989, 0.192381}, {0.991856, 0.177432}, ....
```

but i want to have it in one line like

```
{0.579989, 0.192381 , 0.991856, 0.177432, ...
```

how do i have to change my command?

thanks

Comment: So you need just one column? Looks like you want to take only first number form each pair...

Comment: i want to import both excel coloumns but the data should be single and not as a pair of data like above  {0.579989, 0.192381 , 0.991856, 0.177432,....

Comment: use `Flatten`...

Comment: sorry..what is flatten?

Comment: `Flatten` is a built in function that ... err.. flattens your list:) [docs](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Flatten.html)

Comment: Welcome! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: thanks...have found and seems to run..many thanks